# youtube API - strange issue with ZendGdata

Tags: php, youtube-api, zend-gdata

I have installed the ZendGdata PHP library into /var/www/html on my
local fedora machine. I am trying to learn to use the youtube API by
following the instructions at this link
http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/php_client_lib.html

Without any changes to the "include_path", i tried opening
InstallationChecker.php in my browser and i get an exception.

```
PHP Extension Errors    Tested
No errors found
Zend Framework Installation Errors      Tested  
0       Exception thrown trying to access Zend/Loader.php using
'use_include_path' = true. Make sure you include Zend Framework in
your include_path which currently contains: .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/
share/php

SSL Capabilities Errors Not tested
YouTube API Connectivity Errors Not tested
```

Ok. Now thats pretty normal. Next, I append the ZendGdata library path
to "include_path"  using the below code at the top of InstallationChecker.php

```
$clientLibraryPath = '/var/www/html/phplibs/ZendGdata/library';  
$oldPath = set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR .$clientLibraryPath);
```

Now i get an Servor 500 error when trying to open
InstallationChecker.php in the browser:) thats strange to me. If this is a
permission issue, the page should not have opened before. Right?  I
disabled the above 2 lines of code and i get the error previously displayed.
(already shown above)

Any of you faced this issue? thanks in advance guys for your help...
My PHP version is 5.3 if that would help.
For php --ini, i get

[myname@localhost ~]$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php.d/dom.ini,
/etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php.d/gd.ini,
/etc/php.d/json.ini,
/etc/php.d/mbstring.ini,
/etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php.d/phar.ini,
/etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php.d/wddx.ini,
/etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php.d/xsl.ini,
/etc/php.d/zip.ini